# Cannot access public instance IP address from inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I just launched two instances inside a VPC. I've configured the security group to allow all traffic from instances in the same security group. Both instances share this security group. I've assigned each instance an elastic IP, which is a public IP. The two instances are unable to communicate with each other using this IP, but if I use the private IP of both instances then everything works fine. How can I enable to usage of public IPs inside this VPC / security group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html:

> When you specify a security group as the source or destination for a
>   rule, the rule affects all instances associated with the security
>   group. Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses
>   of the instances that are associated with the source security group
>   (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).

Public (Elastic IP or not) and private IP addresses are *not* interchangeable.  The public IP is a NATed address (Network Address Translation).  It does not resolve to `localhost` from the instance (unless you've edited your /etc/hosts) and it does not work with security group membership.